# Generate Multiple Lot Numbered Inventory through Item Receipt(Code attached): SuiteScript 1.0 Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, inventory

I am trying to generate multiple lots numbered inventory, But it only create only one lot number and getting assigned to that item inventory, Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
    var poid =15513;
var sublistcount = 2;

var fromrecord;
var fromid;
var torecord;
var trecord;
var qty;
fromrecord = 'purchaseorder';
fromid = poid;
torecord = 'itemreceipt';

fulfillment_record = nlapiTransformRecord(fromrecord, fromid, torecord,true);
for(var i=1;i<=sublistcount;i++)
{
      var warehousequantity= 2;
      //var po_line_count = fulfillment_record.getLineItemCount('item');
      fulfillment_record.selectLineItem('item', i);
      fulfillment_record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'itemreceive', 'F');
      fulfillment_record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', warehousequantity);

      for(var j=1;j<=warehousequantity;j++)
      {
            var subrecord = fulfillment_record.editCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');
            if(subrecord!=null){
                subrecord = fulfillment_record.editCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');
                subrecord.insertLineItem('inventoryassignment',j);
              }else {
                  subrecord = fulfillment_record.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');
              }
            subrecord.selectLineItem('inventoryassignment', j);
            subrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', 2);
            subrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'itemreceive ', 'F');
            subrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'serialnumbers', 'XZY'+j);
            subrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'receiptinventorynumber','XYZ'+j);
            subrecord.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');
            subrecord.commitLineItem('inventorydetail');
            subrecord.commit();
            fulfillment_record.commitLineItem('item');
            fulfillment_record.commitLineItem('inventory');
      }
}
 var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(fulfillment_record, true, false);
```

***As per code sample its should create two lots for each items, but its only getting created 1 the last one i.e XZY2.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fulfillment_record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'itemreceive', 'F');
subrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'itemreceive ', 'F');
```

Don't need to mark *itemreceive* explicity false, if you are going to fulfill it.

```
subrecord.commitLineItem('inventorydetail');
```

You can commit only sublist-lines, since *inventorydetail* is not a sublist, it is not required.

```
subrecord.commit();
```

You don't need to commit subrecord explicitly, since sub-records are saved by NetSuite automatically when you save the parent record.

```
subrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', 2);
```

Here you were trying to commit *inventorydetails* quantity more than that defined on fulfillment line.

An example of the above code in *SuiteScript2*.

**Note:** I've found a few limitations of NetSuite where it doesn't allow setting inventory details in dynamic mode, so I am using non-dynamic mode

```
var poid = 15513;
var sublistcount = 2;

var fromrecord;
var fromid;
var torecord;
var trecord;
var qty;
fromrecord = 'purchaseorder';
fromid = poid;
torecord = 'itemreceipt';

fulfillment_record = record.transform({
  fromType: fromrecord,
  fromId: fromid,
  toType: torecord,
  isDynamic: false
});

var sublistCount = fulfillment_record.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });

for (var i = 0; i < sublistcount; i++) {
  var warehousequantity = 2;

  fulfillment_record.setSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'quantity', value: warehousequantity, line: i });

  var subrecord = fulfillment_record.getSublistSubrecord({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'inventorydetail', line: i });
  if (subrecord) {
    // first insert a new line
    for (var j = 0; j < warehousequantity; j++) {
      subrecord.insertLine({ sublistId: 'inventoryassignment', line: j });
      // set inventory quantity
      subrecord.setSublistValue({ sublistId: 'inventoryassignment', fieldId: 'quantity', value: 1, line: j });
      // set serialnumber
      subrecord.setSublistValue({ sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',fieldId: 'serialnumbers', value: 'XZY' + i + j , line: j });
    }

  // don't commit/submit/save subrecord explicitly
  // since NetSuite saves the sub-record when you save parent record
  }

  // since the record in non-dynamic mode
  // we don't need to commit line
}
var id = fulfillment_record.save();
```

Comment: For item receipt record use `receiptinventorynumber` instead of `serialnumbers`.